Powers of Gaussian primes are NOT collinear
Let $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and let $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ be a prime lying above $p$. Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers.
Is it true that $1, \pi^a, \pi^b$ are collinear in the complex plane if and only if $a = b$?
I think this is true, but I am only able to prove it for the cases: $a = 1, b = 2, 3$.
Equivalently, this is proving
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & \pi^a & \overline{\pi}^a \\ 1 & \pi^b & \overline{\pi}^b \end{vmatrix} = 0$$ if and only if $a = b.$
Or if we write $\pi = \sqrt{p}e^{i \theta}$, then
$$p^{\frac{a + b}{2}}\sin((a - b)\theta) + p^{b/2}\sin(b\theta) = p^{a/2}\sin(a\theta)$$ if and only if $a = b.$

This is false, and a family of counterexamples exists for $a=1$ and $b=4$.
Indeed, when $\pi=c+di$ is a prime such that $(c,d)$ fulfill the Pell-type equation $(3c+1)^2 - 3d^2 = -2$, then one can check directly that $\frac{\pi^4-1}{\pi-1}$ is an integer, so $1$, $\pi$ and $\pi^4$ are collinear. The Pell type equation of course has infinitely many solutions in integers; whether there are also infinitely many leading to Gaussian primes, I don't know, but at least going through the list of small solutions (obtained in the standard way from $(1+\sqrt{3})\cdot (2+\sqrt{3})^k$, where $2+\sqrt{3}$ corresponds the fundamental solution of the ``proper" Pell equation $x^2-3y^2=1$), one gets Gaussian primes for $k=1,2,4,7,23,24,51,52,292,300$. E.g., the first four of those give the Gaussian primes $\pi=c+di$ for $(c,d)\in \{(-2,3), (6,11), (88,153), (-4592, 7953)\}$.

We can't quite declare the OP's conjecture "false" because the existence of infinitely many primes in such a family is an open and probably very difficult problem.  Still your observation looks like very strong evidence that there are infinitely many counterexamples with (a,b)=(1,4).

@NoamD.Elkies Yes, I guess there should be infinitely many for the same heuristic reason we expect infinitely many Mersenne primes (simply because things grow roughly in geometric progression), and an actual proof should be out of reach since even plugging the Pell equation into $c^2+d^2$ without assuming that $d$ is also an integer would require to find infinitely many prime values of the quadratic polynomial $4c^2+2c+1$.

@NoamD.Elkies I don't see anything in the question about "apart from finitely many exceptions", so doesn't a single counterexample falsify it?

@Will Sawin Ah, you're right --
such questions often allow for finitely many exceptions,
but the OP conjectured a flat "if and only if",
so each of the examples that Joachim König found
does suffice to falsify the conjecture.

Here are some ideas. Assume that $1$, $\pi^a$, $\pi^b$ are collinear. Then
$$\frac{\pi^b-1}{\pi^a-1}\in\mathbb{Q}(i)\cap\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}.$$
Now let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then, in the ring of Gaussian integers, the greatest common divisor of the ideals $(\pi^a-1)$ and $(\pi^b-1)$ is $(\pi^d-1)$, whence
$$\frac{\pi^a-1}{\pi^d-1},\frac{\pi^b-1}{\pi^d-1}\in\mathbb{Z}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{\pi^a-1}{\pi^d-1},\frac{\pi^b-1}{\pi^d-1}\in i\mathbb{Z}.$$
